# Can the tehniques of higher level mathematics solve most of Olympiad level math problems through straighforward applications?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

Working through many Olympiad math problems(pre-undergrad) I've found that simple applications of undergrad math will solve many of them. Does this trend go on? Can it be that Putnam problems are straightforward applications of math studied at grad level?

For those who still may not know to what I'm referring to, take the example of solving euclidean geometrical problems using Cartesian geometry. In this case you could say that the Descartes's theory replaced the "tricky" challenge of finding the right combinations of axioms to solve a euclidean geometrical problem.

Are there nice counterexamples to this?

Ultimately, could theory building replace "tricky problem solving"?

Comment: no, of course it helps, but there is a huge difference between studying/understanding concepts and solving problems.

Comment: What helps? What do you mean by "of course it helps"?

Comment: I'm just saying that highest level maths go deeper into the concepts, not into the strategies for solving problems. I'd even say that computer science is much more about the strategies for problems solving that theoretical mathematics are.

Comment: Many Olympiad problems are chosen so that they can't be solved using methods taught at higher levels. The idea being to make solving the problems more about clever thinking than about learning the undergraduate syllabus. also, unless you're a computer it's not really practical to solve geometry problems by a coordinate bash. But you do occasionally come across an inequality based Olympiad problem that can be killed with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Almost always, understanding the problem is THE key. Through examples, counter examples etc. Then, when you understand the problem, you build a strategy to prove it. With the latter, more you know the better. But "more you know" doesn't help, if you don't "understanding the problem". Also, "more you know" implies some sort of "intuition", e.g. applying Cartesian geometry may end up with involved calculations, maybe vectors or complex numbers will reveal some nice shortcuts, because, typically, during the competition, you have limited time to solve the problems.

Comment: And, while as an adult mathematician, you can solve those problems within a week, try to solve them within a day. It's a mathematical sport and, like with any sport, you should be trained for it.